# How to input data objects in application code and use workbench created jar in drools project?

Tags: eclipse, jar, drools, kie-workbench

here is a code to load workbench created jar file from application code

```
KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieContainer kContainer = ks.newKieContainer(
ks.newReleaseId("com.myprojects",   "myProject", "LATEST"));
KieScanner kScanner = ks.newKieScanner( kContainer );
kScanner.start( 10000L );
KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession("defaultKieSession");
kSession.insert( fact );
```

How to insert "fact"?
Suppose data object contain member named x. How can I use x without getting a compilation error since the jar file is loaded dynamically?

Comment: Surely the class of `fact` must be known to the Workbench when rules and stuff is being created. How else could it work.

Answer (score 0):

A good approach is always to separate your model classes from your rules in different jars. This way, your kjar (the jar containing the rules) will depend on your model jar and your client code (the one creating the KIE Session) will also depend on you model jar.

Because your client code now "knows" the model before even "knowing" the rules, you can use it without any compilation error.

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 0):

You will have to put the class of the 'fact' object into your projects classpath. If you are using maven then it would be as simple as adding the location of the built workbench jar into your project pom.xml and then you can do this.

Example :

package org.myorg.mydrools.client;

import org.someorg.somepackage.SomeFact;

```
public void loadAndRun() {

  SomeFact fact = new SomeFact();
  fact.x = "some message";

  KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
  KieContainer kContainer = ks.newKieContainer(
  ks.newReleaseId("com.myprojects",   "myProject", "LATEST"));
  KieScanner kScanner = ks.newKieScanner( kContainer );
  kScanner.start( 10000L );
  KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession("defaultKieSession");

  kSession.insert( fact );
}
```